# SQL Server 2014 packages from SSDT 2015

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2014

Hello I created a package in SSDT 2015 and I am trying to run it on SQL Sever 2014.

I tried "save a copy of .." and got it saved on the SQL server.  When I create a Job and try to execute the package I get an error:

> Could not load package "\pl_dump" because of error 0x80131430.

I have been trying to get this working for days and see so many different tutorials and different software to download with no success.  Does anyone know how to deploy and run a package from SSDT 2015 to SQL server 2014?

Comment: Last time I checked, we could run earlier version packages into newer versions, but not vice versa. That means, reverse compatibility is not supported.

Comment: I found that I can downgrade the package to 2014 in the project properties!

Comment: @MrDellimore i downvoted your question because you reposted the correct answer instead of accepting it.

Comment: I didn't see the answer until later.  I appreciate the resource though.  Sorry I am new to stack overflow and not sure the proper etiquette in commendation.

Answer (score 0):

when creating package using visual studio 2015 you have to select that this package is targeted to SQL Server 2014.

Go To the integration services project properties -> Configuration properties -> Set TargetServerVersion to **SQL Server 2014**

[image]

*Side Note: SSDT 2013 is the related version for developing SQL SERVER 2014 packages, but SSDT 2015 supports backward compatibility*

Comment: I couldn't find your setting in my VS 2010(SSIS 2012).

Comment: @PrabhatG BACKWARD COMPATIBILITY STARTS WITH VS 2015

Comment: A user is allowed to accept any answer they choose, even if it's one they post themselves. The problem here was they didn't give proper credit to you (@Hadi) for the suggestion to downgrade. I've corrected that by editing their answer to what it should have looked like to begin with. It doesn't look to me like an attempt to plagiarize. I interpret "I found that I can" as a sideways reference to your answer, evidence more of poor English skills than an attempt to steal credit. Also, I'm not deleting their answer by mod fiat; it can stand on its own merits now and be voted on by the community.

Answer (score 0):

[As Hadi suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45376003/366904), I downgraded the package to SQL Server 2014 in the project properties.

I then saved the package on the file system and set the folder security to "everyone" on the server after getting permission issues.  I also made sure to set the security of the package and project to encrypt sensitive data with a password.